# Has anyone been able to hotdeploy using m2eclipse on Websphere 6.1 with MyEclipse?

Tags: maven-2, m2eclipse, myeclipse, websphere-6.1, hotdeploy

I've been looking around for a while how can I hotdeploy my projects when using m2eclipse plugin on MyEclipse and working with Websphere 6.1.

What I've done so far is to deploy my full application using the was6 maven plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/was6-maven-plugin/) but that plugin will only deploy the EAR into the Websphere.So whenever I have to change just one line of code I have to redeploy the application again. The server doesn't take the changes just by saving the modified source code or JSP file.

I am working with MyEclipse 8.5 IDE and with the original m2eclipse plugin (Not Maven4MyEclipse).

Has anyone been able to do that? And if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) is a commercial solution that would make your life much easier.  It's cheap (like $60).  I actually bought a personal license intead of waiting for my company to purchase it.  There is a free 30 day trial!

JRebel will hotswap your .class files and resources.  No need to maven package, just save the resource in Eclipse, and JRebel will put on the server.  There a few limitations, but in my opinion, its a life save.

We have used JRebel on Jetty, and I have read it is supported on WAS.